# How to selectively forbid deleting of tasks in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, properties

I am new to SharePoint, sorry if answer to my question is obvious.

I want to forbid deleting some tasks for users. 
I can use event receiver for my purpose:

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{  
    if (...) 
    {
        properties.ErrorMessage = "The task can not be deleted";
        properties.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But I can't pass data for checking if I can delete the task. 
I've tryed to use

```
properties.ListItem.Properties["ForbidDeleting"].ToString().Equals("true")
```

in the receiver's condition but is there any posibility to pass such propterty in the CreateTask invoking method? I've tryed using ExtendedProperties for it, but this approach  doesn't work.

```
 ....
 task.ExtendedProperties["ForbidDeleting"] = "true"
```

I can create my class for keeping task Guids and it ForbidDeleting property, but I think it is not a solution but workaround.

Could you help me please? How can I set some task properties (in the CreateTask invoking method) and get it in the event receiver. Is there any built in way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

PS: Sorry for my writing. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I have to use code like this in the Event Receiver to retreive extended properties:

```
Hashtable extendedProperties = SPWorkflowTask.GetExtendedPropertiesAsHashtable(taskItem);
var value = extendedProperties[key].ToString();
```

Thanks to Alexander: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32341/how-to-selectively-forbid-deleting-of-tasks-in-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

You can override another method in your event receiver: [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx). You would set a field that you could use later in the deletion condition:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    // Decide if this task should be deletable.
    properties.AfterProperties["ForbidDeleting"] = true;
}
```

You have to make sure that the boolean *ForbidDeleting* field exists in the task list; either by using your template to create it or by using a list event receiver to do the same or by doing it manually before you add the first task.

If you want to set the *ForbidDeleting* flag first after the task (list item) is really (successfully) created you could override [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) but then update the list item explicitly after the change.

--- Ferda

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is good idea, but I've found the better solution for my needs.